# Trying to rig cloth and Cloth is getting deformed when apply transfer data

Tags: rigging

So I'm trying to rig this cloth (my first try and I know its no where near good but i gotta start from somewhere) as soon as I apply data transfer it deforms, as for my method I make vertex group then use that group in armature modifier (which I get by parenting cloth with rig in object mode) then I add data transfer select options as shown below and then I apply, even If i move data transfer above it still deforms the only difference it makes is that its deformed before applying

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybKtb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQxbd.jpg

Comment: It looks like it has a different rest pose.  The cloth needs to have the same "rest pose" as the armature.  You can't parent a T-pose shirt to an A-pose rig.

Comment: @Nathan sorry for late reply, I tried your solution and it worked Idk why I didn't thought about it, Thanks man.